# How to retrieve protobuf data rendomly?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to store large amount of data in a protobuf format in which include time-stamp parameter. And I want to retrieve the data based on the time-stamp value.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with creating a normal message with a timestamp entry inside?

Comment: @dutt I want to know how to read the data from .pb file based on desired time-stamp value?

Comment: Ah, so you already know how to store it? The easiest way seem to be to do something like message field { string foo = 1; string timestamp = 2; } message data { repeat field = 1; } and then just de-serialize it as usual and loop through the fields until you come across your time stamp. If you want faster lookup than O(n) I think you need to use another format that support random access in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf is a sequential-access format.  There's no way to jump into the middle of a message looking for data; you have to parse through the whole thing.

Some options:

- Devise a framing format that allows you to break up your datastore into many small chunks, each of which is a separate protobuf message.  This is a fairly large project.
- Use SQLite or even an actual database.
- Use a random-access-fieldly format like [Cap'n Proto](http://capnproto.org) instead.  (Disclosure:  I'm the author of Cap'n Proto, and also of Protobufs v2 (Google's open source release).)